# DispatchQueue.main.async availability iOS 10 works on prior iOS

Tags: ios, swift

After migration to new `swift 3`we've got a lot of automatic syntax changes among which:

```
DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
    // Do something
})
```

documentation says that it's available in `iOS 10` and later.
So I expected to see `unrecognized selector` error when running on iOS 8 but it still works.

So I'm just wondering if it would affect some users since our deployment target is `iOS 8`?

[image]

Comment: I think you might miss read the doc, check this out: https://developer.apple.com/reference/dispatch/dispatchqueue/2016103-async it clearly says it's available since iOS 8

Comment: Grand Central Dispatch has been available since 10.6 and iOS 4. What changed was that Swift 3 provided a different calling convention compared to prior Swift versions. And Swift 3 was released around the same time as iOS 10. The documentation is misleading.

Comment: I was referring to quick help, screenshot attached

Answer (score 0):

I just tested it on an iPod touch running 8.4 and `DispatchQueue.main.async{}` works just fine.

The docs are misleading (wrong?)

I went to log a documentation problem, but wait, among lots of other stuff that's been removed from the Xcodebuilt-in documentation system, you can't log issues with the docs anymore!

I suggest filing a radar bug, then.